# How to stop jquery validation on form load event in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

Login.cshtml

```
@model UserModel
<script> src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js">  
</script>   
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js">  
</script>  
<form id="form-submit" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Update" method="post" 
class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group padding-left">
        <label asp-for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>


public class UserModel
{
    [Required]        
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
 }

  //controller action
  public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromQuery] UserModel)
   {
     return View("Login", UserModel);
   }
```

With above markup code & jquery validation script, form field validation happens even before user interaction with input fields i.e., when form loading up on the browser, it is loading up the fields along with validation related error messages.

But my expectation is form field validation should happen ONLY when user interacts with the controls and provided some invalid inputs. What Im missing? How to achieve it?

Comment: HI@ecma-402, You don’t want the code to be validation on the front end but on the back end,right?

Comment: No @XinranShen , I want validation to happen on the front end but NOT while rendering the view/form controls but only during focus event or key up event basically validation is expected to happen ONLY when user interacts with the controls and provided some invalid inputs but NOT before user interaction with the controls

Comment: could you please discribe your requirement in another way. actually i can't understand what you say.

Comment: @XinranShen, when view is loading in the browser it loading with validation failed error message but I want to validation to happen only when user interacts with the controls not before user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the view code, Validation is only triggered when the user clicks the submit button

```
@model UserModel
<form id="form-submit" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Update" method="post" 
class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group padding-left">
        <label asp-for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />     
         <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
   <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
   <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
}
```

[image]

Comment: On top of button click, also need validation on "focusin","focusout" & "keyup event"

Comment: Generally speaking, when submitting, we will verify all attributes and display an error message. why you need validation on `focusin` , `focusout` & `keyup event`?

Comment: Thanks @xinranshen, answer to solve the issue I have repeated is to do ModelState.Clear(); this will stop browser reporting validation failed while loading the page.

Comment: I don't understand which part prevents the validation from firing on page load? I have the same code but it fires as soon as the page has finished loading and shows errors for reach required property.